# Write column backwards with condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df and want to write the number column backwards and also overwrite other values if necessary. The condition is to always use the previous value unless the new values difference to the old value is greater than 10%.

```
Date      Number
2019        150
2018        NaN
2017        118
2016        NaN
2015        115
2014        107
2013        105
2012        NaN
2011        100
```

Because of the condition the value in e.g. 2013 is equal to 100, because it is not smaller than 90 and not greater than 110. The result would look like this:

```
Date      Number
2019        150
2018        115
2017        115
2016        115
2015        115
2014        100
2013        100
2012        100
2011        100
```

Comment: correct. i edited it

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse your column and then `apply` a function to update values. Finally reverse the column to the original order:

```
def get_val(x):
    global prev_num
    if x and x > prev_num*1.1:
        prev_num = x
    return prev_num


prev_num = 0
df['number'] = df['number'][::-1].apply(get_val)[::-1]
```

Comment: that is a nice solution. My real dataframe has several different identities I would like to group your code over. However, when I try:  
`df['number'] = df.groupby("id")['number'][::-1].apply(get_val)[::-1] `, I get Exception: Column(s) number already selected

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. It assumes the first value 100 is not `NaN` and the original dataframe is ordered descending by year. If performance is an issue, the loop can be converted to a list comprehension.

```
lst = df.sort_values('date')['number'].ffill().tolist()

for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    if abs(lst[i] - lst[i-1]) / lst[i] <= 0.10:
        lst[i] = lst[i-1]

df['number'] = list(reversed(lst))

#    date  number
# 0  2019   150.0
# 1  2018   115.0
# 2  2017   115.0
# 3  2016   115.0
# 4  2015   115.0
# 5  2014   100.0
# 6  2013   100.0
# 7  2012   100.0
# 8  2011   100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just groupby the difference after floor division by 10 which is not equal to zero then transform the min i.e

```
df['x'] = df.groupby((df['number'].bfill()[::-1]//10).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['number'].transform(min)


  date  number      x
0  2019   150.0  150.0
1  2018     NaN  115.0
2  2017   118.0  115.0
3  2016     NaN  115.0
4  2015   115.0  115.0
5  2014   107.0  100.0
6  2013   105.0  100.0
7  2012     NaN  100.0
8  2011   100.0  100.0

​
```

Comment: That is nice, but I think it only works if the number gets bigger by time, i.e. what happens if 2019 would be 50 instead of 150?

Comment: It is, because  I was talking about the difference, i.e. (150-50)= 100 > 15.

Comment: @FriedrichFranz to clarify whats the exact output if its 50 rather than 150?

Comment: If number in 2019 would be 50, x should be 50, too. Sorry, I should have stated the example more clearly